# Webkit.Net C#: How to import JavaScript in HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webbrowser-control, webkit.net

I'm developing a C# application using Webkit.Net component. To be cleared, documentText is the only way to display dynamically generated HTML strings.

As title shown, is it possible to have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
```

on HTML Head section, to be included as part of the HTML string? I know in order to render image, I need to convert the images(from local file) into URi. So, how about javascript or jquery?

Comment: can u explain more, r u trying to load/import html just as we included js files in header section of page?

Comment: Yes, Im trying to include js files at the header section of html page. And then, use loadHTML() function to display it in webkitbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this cannot be done with .documentText, which is the only HTML strings supports in Webkit.Net.

In the latest Webkit wrapper: [Open Webkit Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/), it have got an API call, **loadDocument()**, whereby it display from the directory path of HTML file, JavasSript calling can be done locally in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

All local references must be converted. If appropriate, I'd recommend using the `<base>` tag. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Do you mean converting the JavaScript? I don't understand :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this javascript function to load js files in your header section...

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
            if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
               // alert('called');
                var fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
                alert('called');
            }
            else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
                var fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
            }
            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
        }
```

Call this function as

```
loadjscssfile('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js','js');
```

Comment: Just tried :) It doesn't worked for me. I would think importing JavaScript as similar as displaying an image in Webkit.Net C# webBrowser component. Which is to convert the image source into uri type first.

Comment: No error, just the webkit.net webBrowser failed to include the js. Basically the js is to alert a message, but nothing shown. Do you awared that I'm actually talking about webkit.Net C#? Not the normal HTML web page?

Comment: i am afraid you have to explore all the properties and methods of webKitBrowser object...